# ElectronNet -ERROR:gpu_init.cc(523)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is

Tags: electron, electron-builder

When launching the electron app, i get the below error:
ERROR:gpu_init.cc(523)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is

Below are the details:
ElectronNet.Api =>13.5.1
ElectronNet.CLI =>23.6.1
.Net Core 6

I tried updating the ElectronNet.Api to 23.6.1 , but i was getting SocketIOClient Exception("Cannot connect to localhost")

Pleas guide me the solution to this issue. Been stuck for many days.